# Find out which process prevents to modify application data files

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Sometimes it happens, that some files of my application are used by some processes. For example, user opens application log, or something like that, and forgets to close it. This causes some errors while installing/upgrading/uninstalling. In such cases, I'd like to find out, what process is using file, and show user a message, indicating, that files are used.

Is it possible in Inno Setup to find out, what process prevents script from modifying file? At least, when I'm trying to do this in `Code` section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Inno Setup can automatically check, if the installed files are locked by some processes, and offer a user to close (and restart later) the applications automatically (since 5.5.0).

Make sure the [`CloseApplications` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplications) is set to its default value `yes`.

Though by default, only `*.exe,*.dll,*.chm` files are checked. If you want to check also other or all other files, modify the [`CloseApplicationsFilter` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_closeapplicationsfilter):

```
[Setup]
; default
CloseApplications=yes
; check all files
CloseApplicationsFilter=*.*
```

---

If you are installing some files by a code, use the [`RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResources` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResources):

```pascal
procedure RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResources;
begin
  RegisterExtraCloseApplicationsResource(
    False, ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\My Program.log')); 
end;
```

---

[image]